# How to let 30% minus 20% return 10% in JavaScript, C# and Java?

Tags: java, javascript, c#

The following code leads my game app to a strange behavior! I tried the same code In some modern languages such as Java C# and here is the JavaScript version!

```
   var x = .3 - .2,
       y = .2 - .1,
       areEqual= (x == y),
       xIsDotOne = x == .1,
       yIsDotOne = y== .1;
```

`areEqual` is false, `xIsDotOne` is false but `yIsDotOne` is true.

So how to let them return the exact value?

Comment: You can't; compare with a margin of error. Welcome to floating-point numbers.

Comment: Floating point number precision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: FWIW: Double in C#/Java and numbers in JavaScript use the same underlying representation (64-bit IEEE 754 'doubles'). I would expect them all to have the same result for this particular case.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Agree with welcome to jungle with floats, but answering your question... 

    `yIsDotOne == .1`

is not a valid expression that's why different results.

If you do:
    
    `yIsDotOne = y == .1`

you will get false as expected...

Comment: @JordiCastilla typing mistake... `yIsDotOne = y == .1;`